# Change max number of products on shop pages

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using a child theme to the default WooCommerce Storefront theme. I would like to change the maximum number of products shown on the shop pages, to be unlimited (no pagination).

How would you go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this code to your `functions.php`:

```
/**
 * Change number of products that are displayed per page (shop page)
 */
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', 'new_loop_shop_per_page', 20 );

function new_loop_shop_per_page( $products ) {
  // Return the number of products you wanna show per page.
  $products = 100;
  return $products;
}
```

Change the **100** for more if you need it, since you don't want pagination simply put a high number and you won't have pagination.

[Change the number of products displayed per page](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-number-of-products-displayed-per-page/)

Comment: Thanks! If you can just change the `$cols`variable to `$products` or something more descriptive, just to avoid confusion for future reference, I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: You are right, done ;)

Comment: Actually just a small correction: the number of products per page isn't based on the value under Settings -> Reading.